# Slack response to user from bot

Tags: node.js, bots, slack-api, slack

Writing a botuser for my Application and missing one last step while giving response back to the user.

So once user authed, I have stored the information response. Here it is

```
{"ok":true,"access_token":"xoxp-SENSITIVEDATA_MAIN_ACCESSTOKEN-","scope":"identify,bot","user_id":"U2YT_SENSITIVE","team_name":"gsuresh","team_id":"T2Y_SENSITIVE","bot":{"bot_user_id":"U2Z_SENSITIVE","bot_access_token":"xoxb-SENSITIVE_BOT_ACCESSTOKEN"}}
```

Using that information from my rest client I am trying to hit the user from my bot, but with no success. Here is what I have tried so far

Attempt 1:

---

url: https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

payload:

```
{
    "token": "xoxb-SENSITIVE_BOT_ACCESSTOKEN",   // used bot accees token 
    "channel": "U2YT_SENSITIVE", // user id 
    "text": "Whats up dude? I am bot",
    "as_user" :true    
}
```

response:

```
{
"ok": false
"error": "not_authed"
"warning": "missing_charset"
}
```

Attempt 2:

---

url: https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

payload:

```
{
    "token": "xoxp-SENSITIVEDATA_MAIN_ACCESSTOKEN",   // used main accees token 
    "channel": "U2YT_SENSITIVE",
    "text": "Whats up dude? I am bot",
    "as_user" :true    
}
```

response:

```
{
"ok": false
"error": "not_authed"
"warning": "missing_charset"
}
```

What could be the reason? I left with no clues.

Comment: Should "scope":"identify,bot" be "scope":"identify:bot"?

Comment: That is the response from slack server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work, because you are missing the right scope.

To post a message your token needs to have the scope `chat:write:bot` or `chat:write:user`, depending on how you want to sent the message. If you want it to come from the bot use the "chat:write:bot" obviously and "as_user" = false for the API call.

It has nothing to do with using GET or POST to call the API. Both will work.

See authorship section in chat.postMessage method [docu](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship).

Answer (score -1):

You Cannot make a post request to that API. Unfortunately that is a get request which is very weird with that kind of sensitive data. Here is the complete get request curl

```
var url ="https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token="+botaccesstoken+"&channel="+user+"&text="+message+"&as_user=true&pretty=1";
```

That will work.

Comment: Actually, once can make a POST request and it's preferred. You just need to make sure you're using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST bodies, as JSON is not currently accepted for Web API write methods.